# s3cmd - sync command and remote_copy copies different files?

Tags: amazon-s3, s3cmd

I used the s3cmd sync command to sync a directory from a server to a s3 bucket. However, after s3cmd has uploaded all the files, it now does a "remote copy" - why is that the case? Additionally I do see logs like this:

```
remote copy: 'media/image/0e/f8/67/hof_570_1920x1920@2x.jpg' -> 'media/image/32/75/e6/hof_570_1280x1280@2x.jpg'
remote copy: 'media/image/10/95/db/Suesslupinen_1100x1100@2x.jpg' -> 'media/image/25/8f/e2/Suesslupinen_550x550@2x.jpg'
```

So it copies a file to another location and renames the file? This should not be the case, should it?

Comment: Side-note: These days, it is recommended to use the official [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) rather than `s3cmd`.